# JSON cannot be parsed because of whitespaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So I use jQuery to parse JSON from a website (that has the following content):

```
{
"code": 200,
"msg": "OK",
"data": {
    "zone": "EXAMPLE",
    "date": "21 Dec 2017",
    "item": {
        "name": "John Doe",
        "age": 53
    }
  }
}
```

and use objects in that JSON to change the HTML content:

```
$.getJSON('https://api.example.com/', function(data) {
            document.getElementById('firstObject').innerHTML = data.data.item.name;
            document.getElementById('secondObject').innerHTML = data.data.item.age;
```

unfortunately, it won't work. So, I try using another website (that has near-same content like before but **without whitespaces**):

```
{"code":200,"msg":"OK","data":{"zone":"EXAMPLE","date":"21 Dec 2017","item":{"name":"Ben Herton","age":24}}}
```

and use objects in that JSON to change the HTML content:

```
$.getJSON('https://api.secondExample.com/', function(data) {
            document.getElementById('firstObject').innerHTML = data.data.item.name;
            document.getElementById('secondObject').innerHTML = data.data.item.age;
```

And it worked. But, sadly I want to use the first website to use in my project. Perhaps anybody can help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `data.name` & `data.age` are both undefined in your posted code. It should be `data.item.name` & `data.item.age`. And i'm not sure what whitespaces are you talking about?!

Comment: shouldn't they be respone.data.item.name and response.data.item.age assuming the parameter in your callback is response?

Comment: It should actually be `data.data.item.name` and `data.data.item.age` (*first `data` being the name of the variable*)

Comment: see the hierarchy of the required object.  I am assuming you have stored above object in result variable then you can access name value like this `result.data.item.name'

Comment: sorry guys that was a typo. i've corrected it

Answer (score 0):

It is likely the line breaks, rather than whitespace causing issues.

One option is to get the data as a string then parse it manually. Getting the data back as a string gives you the opportunity to parse out other issues as well. So the `JSON.parse` below is just one option

```
 $.ajax({url: 'https://api.example.com/',
        dataType: 'string'}).done(function(dataStr) {
    var cleaned = dataStr.replace(/\n/g,' ');
    // other cleaning can be done prior to parsing too
    var data = JSON.parse(cleaned);
    document.getElementById('firstObject').innerHTML = data.name;
    document.getElementById('secondObject').innerHTML = data.age;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

worked ok for me

```js
var d = {
  "code": 200,
  "msg": "OK",
  "data": {
    "zone": "EXAMPLE",
    "date": "21 Dec 2017",
    "item": {
      "name": "John Doe",
      "age": 53
    }
  }
};


$(document).ready(function() {
  document.getElementById('firstObject').innerHTML = d.data.item.name;
  document.getElementById('secondObject').innerHTML = d.data.item.age;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="firstObject">
</div>
<div id="secondObject">
</div>
```